# AgGrid Expandable pivot group column not collapsing

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

I am creating a pivot grid with ag-grid. Docs and examples show pivot column groups collapsed by default, as described in

[docs - pivot column groups](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/pivoting/#pivot-column-groups)

Reproducible example - https://codepen.io/spacer212/pen/mdaPXvY

[image: Current Pivot table view]

I am looking to collapse the column group by years.

Any help is appreciated

I tried using the example code in the doc referenced above.

```
const rowData = [{
"date":1577923200000,"ticker__Sector":"Group1","values":18},
{"date":1577923200000,"ticker__Sector":"Group2","values":32},
{"date":1577923200000,"ticker__Sector":"Group3","values":26},
{"date":1578009600000,"ticker__Sector":"Group1","values":4},
{"date":1578009600000,"ticker__Sector":"Group2","values":13},
{"date":1578009600000,"ticker__Sector":"Group3","values":11},
{"date":1609718400000,"ticker__Sector":"Group1","values":48},
{"date":1609718400000,"ticker__Sector":"Group2","values":10},
{"date":1609718400000,"ticker__Sector":"Group3","values":12},
{"date":1609804800000,"ticker__Sector":"Group1","values":64},
{"date":1609804800000,"ticker__Sector":"Group2","values":20},
{"date":1609804800000,"ticker__Sector":"Group3","values":27},
{"date":1641168000000,"ticker__Sector":"Group1","values":12},
{"date":1641168000000,"ticker__Sector":"Group2","values":3},
{"date":1641168000000,"ticker__Sector":"Group3","values":17},
{"date":1641254400000,"ticker__Sector":"Group1","values":22},
{"date":1641254400000,"ticker__Sector":"Group2","values":4},
{"date":1641254400000,"ticker__Sector":"Group3","values":31},
{"date":1672704000000,"ticker__Sector":"Group1","values":8},
{"date":1672704000000,"ticker__Sector":"Group2","values":16},
{"date":1672704000000,"ticker__Sector":"Group3","values":13},
{"date":1672790400000,"ticker__Sector":"Group1","values":29},
{"date":1672790400000,"ticker__Sector":"Group2","values":33},
{"date":1672790400000,"ticker__Sector":"Group3","values":59}]
```

```
function dateFormatter(params) {
  return moment(params.value).format('MM/DD/YYYY');
}

function dateComparator(date1, date2) {
  var date1Number = date1
  var date2Number = date2

  if (date1Number === null && date2Number === null) {
    return 0;
  }
  if (date1Number === null) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (date2Number === null) {
    return 1;
  }

  return date1Number - date2Number;
}
const columnDefs = [
    
    { field:"Year",
      valueGetter:"new Date(data.date).getFullYear()",
      pivot:true,
      hide:true,
    },
    { field: 'date', 
    valueFormatter: dateFormatter, 
    pivotComparator: dateComparator, 
    pivot:true,

    sort: 'desc'},
    { field: "ticker__Sector" ,rowGroup:true, hide : true},
    { field: "ticker__Industry"},
    { field: "values", aggFunc: 'sum'},
   

  ];
  

  // let the grid know which columns and what data to use
  const gridOptions = {

    columnDefs: columnDefs,
    rowData: rowData,
    pivotMode: true,
    removePivotHeaderRowWhenSingleValueColumn: true,
    sideBar: 'columns',
    defaultColDef: {    flex: 1,    minWidth: 110,    filter: true,    resizable: true,  sortable: true,},
    autoGroupColumnDef: {    minWidth: 200, sortable: true, },
    suppressAggFuncInHeader: true,

    processPivotResultColDef: (colDef) => {
      // console.dir(colDef)
      colDef.headerName = moment(Number(colDef.headerName)).format('MM/DD/YYYY')
      
    },
    // processPivotResultColGroupDef: (colGroupDef) => {
    //       console.dir(colGroupDef)
    // },
  };

  // setup the grid after the page has finished loading
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const gridDiv = document.querySelector('#myGrid');
    new agGrid.Grid(gridDiv, gridOptions);
  });
```